# libgdx stage input processor working in desktop but not in android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my project i have a button in my stage with a listener but the problem is that the listener method changed is fired when running the game in desktop but not fired when running the game in an android device.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: We need to see your code, and also need to know what sort of listener you used, because a click listener in desktop is not always the same on android. Do you use: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html